# Why is rejecting the certificate Java?

Tags: java, x509certificate

I'm trying to authenticate to a REST API using a x509 certificate as shown below:

```
public static String jsonGetRequest(String urlQueryString) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(urlQueryString);
        HttpsURLConnection connection=(HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "file://c:/certificados/truststore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "classpath:client.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "client");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");   

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.connect();
        int responseCode=connection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

I also imported the client certificate to my local certificate manager and the REST API server accepts the connection.
I imported as well the certificate to cacerts.

Java provides the next error while evaluating the function:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  ...

  Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Many possible reasons. You could be setting `javax.net.ssl` properties too late to take effect. Since they are JVM-wide, pass them in as `-D` properties to `java` on the command line. If that doesn't work, run your app with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and look carefully at the output where it loads the truststore and the point in the handshake where it gives up and throws the error.